# Sql NTILE() function with Postalcode

Tags: sql

I am trying to split some records in equal number of decks.  It works fine with sql Ntile(20) function. However the issue is it splits the post code as well. Splitting should happen within the postcode.

```
Select (NTILE(20) OVER(ORDER BY PostalCode ASC)) AS 'DeckNumber' 
from xxx 
order by Postalcode
```

Any ideas how to solve this ?

[image]

Comment: Is this for **SQL Server**?? SQL != SQL Server! SQL is just the structured query language that lots of DB systems use .....

Comment: Unless you have exactly 20 postcodes, a value will always span different postcodes, no? See [MSDN "Ranking Functions"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Comment: I have thousands of postcodes with duplication.

Comment: @pointlesspolitics: in other words, what is your desired output. Show 3 postcodes as an example please

Comment: @gbn Thanks for the input. Basically I cannot use NTILE to split the records with some condition. It just divides records equally.

Comment: @pointlesspolitics: please read what we are asking. I guessed you can't use NTILE. Give proper, sample data

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server - you should be able to do this:

```
SELECT 
   NTILE(20) OVER(PARTITION BY PostalCode ORDER BY PostalCode ASC) AS 'DeckNumber' 
FROM dbo.xxx 
ORDER BY Postalcode
```

This will "partition" your data into groups by `Postalcode`, and inside each group, the `NTILE(20)` function will be applied.

Maybe you want to use a different `ORDER BY` clause inside the `NTILE...OVER()` function - since you're already partitioning by `Postalcode`, also ordering by it doesn't really make a whole lot of sense...

Comment: @gbn: not sure - he says "split into equal number of decks" - that sounds more like `NTILE` (split whole range into 20 blocks of data islands)

Comment: same script as mine +1 and i deleted mine

Comment: @Marc_s,   I tried and it beheaves in a same way as Row_Number(). It spilts the decks with row numbers grouped by postalcode

Comment: @pointlesspolitics: in that case, you're probably really not looking for  `NTILE` - try using `DENSE_RANK() OVER......` as @gbn suggested. Is that giving you want you're looking for??

Comment: @pointlesspolitics: `NTILE` will just break your data into as many groups of rows of roughly equal size - it is used to answer things like: "show me the top 5% of all sales" and so forth. Maybe for your needs, that's not the right function to use